# Lectura y escritura de archivos binarios en c con fread-fwrite

Tags: c, archivo

Estoy intentando leer y escribir archivos binarios. Creo una matriz en la memoria ram, luego la escribo en un archivo binario.

```
void escribirMatrizParcialmente(double ***A){       
    FILE *destino;
    int i,j;

    if((destino=fopen(ARCHIVOMATRIZ,"wb"))==NULL){
        printf("No se pudo abrir el archivo.");
        return;
    }
    for(i=0;i<FILAS;i++){
        fwrite( &A[i][0],sizeof(double),COLUMNAS,destino);  
        //escribo desde el primer elemento de cada fila la cantidad de 
        //columnas 
    }
  fclose(destino);
}
```

`ARCHIVOMATRIZ`,`FILAS` y `COLUMNAS` son constantes.

Bueno esto me da error de Segmentacion default.

No hay error al crear la matriz pues yo la muestro por pantalla antes de escribirla, y si utilizo fprintf para escribir en un archivo de texto funciona correctamente. Con el codigo de abajo escribo en un archivo de texto correctamente la matriz (lo pongo solo para ilustrar y que se vea que mi problema es con fwrite ).

```
for(i=0;i<FILAS;i++){
    for(j=0;j<COLUMNAS;j++){
        fprintf(destino,"%.6lf ",(*A)[i][j]);
    }
    fprintf(destino,"%s","\n");
    }
```

Bueno ademas tengo problemas para leer dicha matriz con `fread` con un codigo bastante similar al de escritura.No da errores de compilacion ni warnings pero cuando muestro la matriz no muestra nada.

```
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<FILAS;i++){
        fread( &A[i][0] ,sizeof(double), COLUMNAS, fuente );    
    }
```

Leo todas las filas desde la matriz y las guardo en mi matriz desde la direccion de memoria inicial de cada fila.

Comment: Para poder responder a tus dudas sería aconsejable que intentases presentar un ejemplo mínimo y completo que reproduzca el problema... poner código suelto tiene el riesgo de que puedes omitir cosas que son realmente importantes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A` es un puntero triple, luego en esta instrucción:

```
fwrite( &A[i][0],sizeof(double),COLUMNAS,destino);
```

Estás escribiendo una posición de memoria en vez de un valor.

Dices que trabajas con una matriz, es decir, con un array de **dos** dimensiones... esto se modela con un array doble y, como te he comentado, aquí estás usando un puntero **triple**. Declarar un puntero triple en este caso solo tendría sentido si la función tiene que reservar memoria para la matriz... o liberarla. en cualquier otro caso, por claridad, lo aconsejable sería usar un puntero doble:

```
void escribirMatrizParcialmente(double **A){       
    FILE *destino;
    int i,j;

    if((destino=fopen(ARCHIVOMATRIZ,"wb"))==NULL){
        printf("No se pudo abrir el archivo.");
        return;
    }
    for(i=0;i<FILAS;i++){
        fwrite( A[i][0],sizeof(double),COLUMNAS,destino);  
        //escribo desde el primer elemento de cada fila la cantidad de 
        //columnas 
    }
  fclose(destino);
}
```

Para los otros problemas te falta información así que el resto de la respuesa tendrá que esperar.

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Me sirvio mucho de ayuda. Era un puntero triple ya que esta funcion se llamaba despues que la funcion que asignaba memoria. Ambas funciones se llamaban dentro de otra principal. Me sirvió para realizar la funcion de lectura tambien. Lo unico es que en la funcion fwrite debo poner el & antes de la matriz, asi:                      
 fwrite( &A[i][0],sizeof(double),COLUMNAS,destino);                                Me sirvio tu ayuda.Gracias de nuevo